# How to print Barcode using Zebra printer RW420 (CPCL language)

Tags: android, zebra-printers

I want to print barcode for my application using Zebra RW420 printer (that uses CPCL language). I am using http://www.ppico.co/guide/823376/ for guidance of print command. Tried printing barcode by using the format and commands given in this guide but it doesnt print anything. Using below command but no help..

```
String cpclConfigLabel = "! 0 200 200 210 1\r\n" //"
                    + "ON-FEED IGNORE\r\n" 
                    + "BARCODE 128 1 1 50 150 10 1234567455"                
                    + ""
                    + "PRINT\r\n";
```

Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new-line sequence to the barcode command ("BARCODE .... \r\n"). Generally speaking, terminate every command line with the new-line sequence).

Comment: yes i noticed after posting the question that i missed putting "\r\n" in the end line at the end of command. Nways thanks :)